Sum of spectral idempotents is the identity
As a refresher for my linear algebra towards the follwing academic course, I am trying the following exercise. Let $A$ be an Hermitian $n\times n$ matrix whose distinct eigenvalues are $\theta_0,\ldots, \theta_d$, with corresponding multiplicites $m_0,\ldots, m_d$. For $i\in \{0,\ldots, d\}$, let $v_0,\ldots, v_{m_i-1}$ be an eigenbasis for the $\theta_i$-eigenspace, which we denote by $V_i$. Let $E_i$ be the projector onto $V_i$ (it will also be the spectral idempotent corresponding to $\theta_i$). Apparently we can write
$$E_i=\sum_{j=0}^{m_i-1}v_iv_i^\times,$$
where $\times$ denotes the conjugate transpose.
I am attempting to show that $\sum_{i=0}^d E_i=I$. I have tried using the definition of $E_i$ from the previous line but got nowhere. Could someone please tell me how to proceed? Preferabily using the definitions I already have, and not different material.

Since $A$ is hermitian, it can be diagonalised by an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. We may therefore assume that the $v_k^{(i)}$ for $i=0, \dots, d$ and $k= 0, \dots, m_i-1$ form an orthonormal basis (the set of $v_k^{(i)}$ for a fixed $i$ is your basis of the $\theta_i$-eigenspace). Let's call the dimension $n$. We have $n=m_0 + \dots + m_d$.
Now for any orthonormal basis $w_1, \dots, w_n$ of $\mathbb F^n$ with $\mathbb F= \mathbb R, \mathbb C$ (with respect to some inner product) we have the formula
$$x= \sum_{i=1}^n \langle w_i, x \rangle w_i.$$
This is easy to see: Since the $w_i$ are a basis, there are scalars $\alpha_i$ such that $x= \sum \alpha_i w_i$. By taking the inner product we obtain from orthonormality
$$\langle w_l, x\rangle = \alpha_l.$$
Here I use the convention that the standard inner product on $\mathbb C^n$ is linear in the second component and conjugate linear in the first one.
Now back to your problem: We have
$$\sum_{i=0}^d E_i(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i v_i^*x = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \langle v_i, x \rangle = x$$
by the above formula.

The formula $E_i = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m_i - 1} v_i v_i^\dagger$ is only true if $v_0,\dots, v_{m_i - 1}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V_i$ (For example, you can easily see that it fails for $A = I$, $\theta = 1$, $v_0 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$).
In this case all $v_i$ for all eigenvalues form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and it should be known at that point that for an orthonormal basis $u_0, \dots, u_{n-1}$ the product $u_i^\dagger x$ is the $i$-th coordinate of a vector $x$, and $\left(\sum_i u_i u_i^\dagger\right) x = \sum_i u_i (u_i^\dagger x) = x$.
